# Don't exit full screen when pressing escape in apps like Safari on Lion

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, osx-lion, fullscreen

In OS X Lion, pressing the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key exits full screen mode.  Unfortunately, and especially when using Safari, <kbd>ESC</kbd> is used for other functions, such as in Javascript keystroke event handling.  I don't want Lion to exit full screen mode when pressing escape, but I can't find a place to disable that functionality.

I already know the keyboard shortcut to Enter/exit full screen mode (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>).  I want to disable the <kbd>ESC</kbd> shortcut. I've been Googling, but cannot find any answers.

Comment: Pressing `Esc` where it has a different effect (e.g. aborting page loading) does not exit full screen.

Comment: @Daniel: But that doesn't necessarily apply to any other functions. Is this actually a wide spread OS X Lion problem? Why are there so few people that are actually experiencing this?

Comment: @Tom Please explain; what other functions?

Comment: @DanielBeck: It's listed in the question: `ESC` is used for other functions as well.

Comment: @Tom Such as? The user doesn't say, and neither do you. I could imagine all those functions overriding the full screen mode shortcut when used by e.g. consuming the event, but without more examples, I can't say for sure.

Comment: @DanielBeck: The users says "other functions", and that's enough.

Comment: I, too, am curious what other functions are being trampled on here.  And I will say that Full Screen is a new feature, and as with any new feature, there are going to be usability issues. You should file this as a bug with Apple (http://bugreport.apple.com), as I'm not sure its the intended behavior.

Comment: Major problem for terminal emulators. It is very common to use the escape key in a terminal session to go back to the previous host screen or exit what you are doing.
Apple needs to provide a way to disable escape so other programs can use it.

Comment: The user so far failed to provide *any* example where `Esc` would produce any other effect and exits full screen anyway. The "examples" in @AJACs' answer don't work either, instead showing a sensible behavior in all cases. Down-voting.

Comment: @Rich As is obvious from Terminal's behavior, programs can disable `Escape` for leaving full screen. iTerm2 also does not close full screen with `Escape`. What, in detail, are you referring to?

Comment: @TomWijsman Interesting. *All* examples brought forth so far *does not work*. Even though there are already two non-answers with "examples" where `Escape` behavior are alleged to be broken, *none* of them actually behave as described. There's a reason I asked for concrete examples right from the start: *There just aren't any*.

Comment: **Accidentally hit enter**
There are many web pages where ESC is used to close a modal window, for example: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/
Click Demo on the page to display a modal window.  Press ESC to close the modal.  Safari is aware that there is a modal window, and doesn't exit full screen.  Press ESC again and Safari exits full-screen mode.

Often I press ESC several times to ensure something gets closed.  I don't want Safari to exit full-screen mode when that happens.  There is already a key command to exit full-screen.  ESC shouldn't be used.

Comment: @Daniel Beck: You're ignoring the scenario where pressing escape causes windows to leave full screen mode if you tap it accidentally. There's no reason for that. Why are you so violently opposed to this question and a request for a solution?

Comment: Scenario: A web page uses Javascript to monitor the escape key, used to close divs and the like. Tapping escape leads to Javascript processing the event AND Lion's misbehavior. Is that sufficient? It is a UI mistake to trigger leaving full screen mode on escape.

Comment: @dpk Link to a demo web page, please. Since none of the examples mentioned so far have this issue when I tested them, I don't believe that without steps to reproduce the issue. In fact, Fadi's example above contradicts your comment.

Comment: @Daniel Beck: Here ya go: http://dpk.net/demonstration-of-escape-problem-in-lion.html . Full screen Safari and then go to that page, click the button, and hit escape to clear the fake dialog. Sorry for the 'tude earlier, bad day.

Comment: @dpk Hmmm... OK. You could use `.keydown()` and `return false;`, then it'd be no issue. But this is finally a working example that doesn't play well with fullscreen `Esc`, at least.

Comment: I've edited the post to add this example. Hopefully we'll/someone'll find a way to work around Apple's error here.

Comment: @dpk I guess I just [admitted defeat](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3715/make-superuser-compatible-to-os-x-lion-full-screen-mode) :-)

Comment: I found ctrl+esc works gmail's hangouts windows close. It may work for other websites too.

Comment: Well, 10 years in and this is _still_ a problem!

Answer (score 12):

Try <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>, which worked for me.

Comment: It doesn't trigger actions associated with the Escape key either, e.g. aborting Safari web page loading.

Comment: Awesome, this works well in Safari 13. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This is kinda hard to get the hang of but seems like the only solution that works well in all situations

Comment: @DanielBeck There're usually other key bindings for those actions, e.g. aborting the loading of a page can be done by pressing `cmd + .` and the tab key can be used to deactivate the address bar.

Answer (score 11):

I didn't find an answer for macOs Sierra and higher.
So that's how i solved this issue.

As it has been already suggested i've remapped ESC to ⌥ + ESC. It does the job and even some other functions assigned to the key works. You will be able to exit fullscreen videos on some sites, but it will not abort page loading.

First you need to install [Karabiner-elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) to be able to remap keys

1. Install [brew](https://brew.sh) `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. Install cask `brew tap caskroom/cask`
3. Install karabiner-elements `brew cask install karabiner-elements`

I've created custom "Complex modification" specifically for this problem. To install this modification you have to:

1. Open karabiner-elements and go to "Complex modifications" tab
2. Click "Add rule" button, then "Import more rules from the Internet"
3. Import modification "Don't exit fullscreen when pressing ESC in Safari"

Answer (score 8):

For web browsers, and specifically for use of sites with behavior that enables or requires use of the `Escape` key while not preventing closing of full screen (like [Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113212/151367)), you can use the following user script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Keep Full Screen
// @namespace     http://superuser.com/q/315949
// @description    Prevents Escape key from leaving full screen.
// @include      http://*
// ==/UserScript==
document.onkeydown = function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 27) evt.preventDefault();
}
```

---

To run this in browsers, use any user script engine for your browser.

- For Safari 5, you can use the Safari extension [NinjaKit](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/os0x/20100612/1276330696) (on [GitHub](https://bitbucket.org/os0x/ninjakit)). This is what I use.
- For Chrome, you can use its [NinjaKit](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gpbepnljaakggeobkclonlkhbdgccfek) variant.
- For any other Safari on OS X, you can use the SIMBL plug-in [GreaseKit](http://8-p.info/greasekit/). Not sure how up to date it is though.

Comment: for convenience's sake, I uploaded this to userscripts: http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/178642

Comment: Any experience installing this on Safari for Mavericks?

Comment: Yeah this doesn't work for me, I'm in Yosemite Beta 5 with Safari 8.0 (10600.1.25) at the time of writing, and using NinjaKit in Safari as the userscripts engine. Escape key keeps on breaking full screen and for me it's happening when I'm in address bar and press Esc while in it. (it has a few useful functions when editing text in it...) I'm assuming GreaseKit no longer works given it's dated to 2009 and a quick google seems to indicate it doesn't work anymore. Any ideas? So frustrating, no wonder Chrome is the go-to primary browser, even on Apple's own operating system...

Comment: @foregon I'd expect page event handling to have absolutely no effect while you're in the address bar.

Comment: works with tampermonkey, edited the script/response to support https:// as well.

Answer (score 4):

Most situations native to OS X accept both `Escape` and `Cmd-.` to abort, e.g. file dialogs, Safari loading, dragging elements around, etc.

Notably absent from that list is, of course, *leaving full screen mode*.

---

So you could just learn to press `Cmd-.` instead of `Escape` to avoid this situation altogether. Or you can teach your computer to do it for you: An at least somewhat sane solution is to use e.g. [Butler](http://manytricks.com/butler/)'s *Keystrokes* item to map `Escape` to `Cmd-.`:

- Open Butler's configuration page
- Select any container, e.g. *Hidden*, click *+ » Smart Item » Keystrokes*
- On the *Keys* tab, press `Cmd-.` to use this as the resulting keystroke when activating this item
- On the *Triggers* tab, select the *Hot Key* input field and press `Escape`. Ignore the warning that basically states you're insane.
- Remember to add e.g. *Terminal* to the exceptions list — it totally ignores `Escape` for leaving full screen, but pressing `Ctrl-.` translates to `Ctrl-C`!

---

In some situations, things will misbehave. Remapping the key to what's *usually* an equivalent keyboard shortcut is a sledgehammer solution. *Quick Look*, for example, doesn't handle `Cmd-.` (and therefore the remapped `Escape` for closing file previews); renaming files in Finder cannot be aborted anymore using `Escape`, nor selections e.g. in Finder be cleared.

In limited testing, I found no situation where pressing `Cmd-.` actually leads to undesirable actions being performed, but be aware that these probably also exist.

Comment: Of course, you could completely ignore all Escape keypresses like this, but that'll lose a good bit of functionality...

Comment: ⌘ + .  exits full screen mode for me in Opera, so this is a no go :(

Answer (score 3):

EASY, found it!
KeyboardMaestro with 2 actions

When pressing "<kbd>ESC</kbd>"
Simulate pressing (instead):
- "<kbd>CMD</kbd>+." 
- THEN also  "<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>"

You need both, because some app react only to one order or the other (sometimes to none, then nothing possible) -- >this way most apps will do like an "<kbd>ESC</kbd>" in their context, but you will never get exited from the full screen mode

Answer (score 2):

Your possible options include:

1. Set alternative shortcuts for the other functions, because <kbd>ESC</kbd> is reserved by the OS and Browser.
2. Adjust the source / assembler machine code to rebind the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key of the OS and Browser.
3. File the bug/feature request against application developer (i.e. Google spreadsheets) to consume ESC event instead of letting it through.
4. File a bug with Apple, because the applications were here first, and Apple re-purposed the key without cause.

Comment: #1 I can get behind.  #2 is almost tongue-in-cheek to the point of laughter.

Comment: Well, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Functions using `Escape` are not usually available from the menu bar, and `Escape` does not trigger menu items as is obvious from the missing "flash" highlighting the menu bar item containing the triggered item.

Comment: #4 File a bug with Apple, because the applications were here first, and Apple re-purposed the key without cause.

Answer (score 1):

Just to flesh out the description a bit more.

ESC is used to cancel a drag, esc is used to cancel a dialog box, esc is used during a drag to cancel a move/copy, esc is used in terminal in VI to cancel an editing command

So, there are numerous uses. It is a weird oddity that Apple has this cancel full screen mode when that is possible by ctrl-cmd-F and the upper right icon.

This seems to be on an app by app basis Mail and Safari and other iLife items will exit full screen. iTunes stays full screen.

Reeder ignores the esc for the purpose of Full window control, and does other appropriate things for the program. Evernote does not even have a cmd-F or ctrl-cmd-F for window control, its the icon and the esc key.

You can't seem to map esc by itself to some non-harmful nonsense action in the keyboard control panel.

Comment: In Safari, mapping the Escape key to a benign function doesn't seem to be a solution.  Regardless of the action, it will still drop out of Full Screen.

Comment: And again, pressing `Escape` to cancel dialogs *does not exit full screen*.

Comment: Pressing `Escape` in Terminal *does not exit full screen*.

Comment: Using `Escape` to cancel a drag *does not exit full screen*. Have you even *tried* it before posting these claims?

Comment: Using `Escape` in Reeder to e.g. return from an article web page to the RSS item *does not exit full screen*. If `Escape` is not used for such an action, it exits full screen. *As in **ALL OTHER PROGRAMS**.*

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using JQuery. In that case:

Listen for **keydown** events (keypress and keyup won't work) on the **document** with **keyCode 27**, and when the event fires call **e.preventDefault()**.

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {

    if (e.keyCode === 27) { // Escape key
        e.preventDefault();
        // Other code goes here    
    }

});
```

Comment: [Related request on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113212/151367), works without jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to have <kbd>esc</kbd> routed to <kbd>alt/option</kbd> + <kbd>esc</kbd>. For the most part, this lets me get out of YouTube vids, and if you have a Squarespace account, it lets you login without getting out of full screen.

- Download and install [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en).
- Go to the right most "Misc & Uninstall" tab.
- Click on the button that says "Open private.xml".
- Download the private.xml file from [here](https://github.com/adityasrini/RandomCode/raw/master/private.xml)
- Replace the original "private.xml" file in Finder with the downloaded file. Voila!

Answer (score 1):

Use BetterTouchTool or KeyboardMaestro or something similar to remap <kbd>Esc</kbd> to ⌥ + <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

After some desperate search for the solution, I consign Safari to a separate virtual desktop with Mission control. This mitigates the ESC problem and is by far the best approximation to a fullscreen Safari window.

Bonus space if you hide the Dock.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as the @aditya-srinivasan answer targeting Opera

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <item>
  <!-- ============================================================ -->
  <appdef>
    <appname>OPERA</appname>
    <equal>com.operasoftware.Opera</equal>
  </appdef>

    <name>Escape to Option + Escape on Opera</name>
    <identifier>private.Opera_escape</identifier> 
    <only>OPERA</only>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::ESCAPE, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L</autogen>
  </item>
  <!-- ============================================================ -->
</root>
```

See @aditya-srinivasan answers on the downloading https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en

Answer (score 0):

Use the combination **⌘+esc** (cmd+esc)
(**⌥+esc** (opt+esc) also works)

This allows the webpage to "esc" whatever is selected (ie: the editing of cells in Google Sheets) without affecting the browser.

Works on Ventura 13.2 with Safari 16.3.